# Referencing an entity from another bundle in Doctrine in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

Firstly, I have already searched this and tried a few solutions but none work - I may well have missed something so this is my issue.

I have three different Bundles in my Symfony 3 project, `AppBundle` (shared one), `ClientBundle` (for clients only) and `AdminBundle` (for admin users only). The only Entity present in the `AppBundle` is `User.php` which is extended from the `FOSUserBundle` in the project, as I needed extra fields. I need to be able to map a field in the User entity to a field in the `Site` entity which is located in the `AdminBundle`, but whenever I try to update the schema, I get the following error:

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]   The target-entity
>   AppBundle\Entity\Site cannot be found in
>   'AppBundle\Entity\User#siteId'.

Currently my mapping looks like this, in `User.php`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AdminBundle\Entity\Site")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="site_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $siteId;
```

As you can see, I have used the full path to the `Site` entity here. I have even included a use statement for the Entity, just in case:

```
use AdminBundle\Entity\Site;
```

But still the same error occurs upon schema update.

Can anyone shed any light on this? I need to be able to get this mapping to work and I cannot move the user entity to the `AdminBundle` as it is required by both admin and client users, and with my config set up, clients are restricted to the `ClientBundle` and the `AppBundle`.

Comment: try `targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\Site"` (remove the leading slash)

Comment: Yep that worked! Think the cache needed clearing as well, so I guess it was that too, thanks.

Comment: I added the answer

Comment: will you please except my answer?

Comment: I have accepted it, sorry have not been online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to `targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\Site"` (remove the leading slash)